# Using Mappy with XNA

Tags: c#, xna, mapping, projects-and-solutions, tiles

I am currently using *MappyWin32 V1.4.23* as well as the '**XNA Content Pipeline Extension to Mappy Maps(.FMP)**' library.

The problem I am having is loading the library into XNA.

I add 'ContentPipelineExtension_MappyMaps' to my current solution as well as 'Module_Basic_Entities, and 'Module_Persistence'.

I reference these in '**WindowsGame3**' and '**WindowsGame3Content (Content)**', however when I go to change the properties in my .FMP file's Content Importer and Content Processor, I see no reference to the above library, meaning I cannot get my map files to load into XNA.

Am I overlooking a simple step?

Is this library still good, or is there something better out there?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the library's reference to your content project references.

Answer (score 0):

Referenced the library's (Knew it was simple!) and that worked out fine.

Now when I try to add the following line:

```
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        this.spriteBatch.Draw(gameTime, this.Map2D, new Vector2(100, 100), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

I get the error

> Error 1   'WindowsGame3.Game1' does not contain a definition for 'Map2D' and no extension method 'Map2D' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsGame3.Game1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\The Binks Family\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsGame3\WindowsGame3\WindowsGame3\Game1.cs 238 50  WindowsGame3

I did add the following code beforehand as well:

```
            Map2D map2D = Content.Load<Map2D>("Home");
```

With "Home" being the name of my .fmp file.

When I select Home.fmp, I see no options under 'Content Importer' or 'Content Processor' regarding the XNA Content Pipeline Extension to Mappy Maps.

[Translated to English, via Google. Documentation regarding this extension](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.sharpgames.net/Artigos/Artigo/tabid/58/selectmoduleid/376/ArticleID/1585/reftab/54/Default.aspx&act=url)

Is this extension outdated or am I just getting tripped up in simple matters again?

If so, is there an easier way to import a tile map for use in my program?